# Keep/restore position if activity start/restart

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a mainactivity which start a new Activity

```
private void newListActivity(){
    Context context = MainActivity.this;
    Class destinationActivity = ListActivity.class;
    Intent startChildActivityIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), destinationActivity);
    startActivity(startChildActivityIntent);
}
```

ListActivity contains a recyclerview with the list items

- If I scroll in my list and I rotate my screen the position is kept.
- If I return to my mainActivity by pressing back button and re-click in my button which launch the newListActivity() the scroll position is lost.

My code ListActivity

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<Trace> _traceDataset = new ArrayList<Trace>();
    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    TraceAdapter mAdapter ;
    String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trace_list);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvTrace);
        initList();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mAdapter = new TraceAdapter(_traceDataset);
        // Set CustomAdapter as the adapter for RecyclerView.
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Then the application is being reloaded
            Log.v(TAG, "savedInstanceState non null-> activity reloaded".toUpperCase());
        }else{
            Log.v(TAG, "savedInstanceState  null-> first activity load".toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    public void initList(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Obj obj = new Obj();
            obj.setName(" GPS " + i);
            obj.setIndex("Element #" + i);
            _traceDataset.add(trace);
        }
        Log.v(TAG, _traceDataset.size());
    }

   /* @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.v("onSaveInstanceState","onSaveInstanceState");
    }*/


    private int someVarA;


       @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //outState.putInt("someVarA", someVarA);
        Log.v("onSaveInstanceState","onSaveInstanceState");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        //someVarA = savedInstanceState.getInt("someVarA");
        Log.v("onRestoreInstanceState","onRestoreInstanceState");


    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // Save ListView state @ onPause
        Log.d(TAG, "ON PAUSE");
        super.onPause();



    }
}
```

Apparently, i can't use the onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState

What's the best way to keep my position ? sharedPreferences between activities ?
Others solutions?
Do you have a sample?

Comment: Why cant you use onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState? The list would be lost when you rotate your screen if you are not using them. Please post your ListActivity code so that we see how you are assigning the adapter.

Comment: My code list has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using to save position in onDestroy and onPause:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.put("savedPosition", position);
editor.commit();
```

and to read in onCreate, onResume:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
int savedPosition = prefs.getInt("savedPosition", 0);
```

Where second argument is default value (here 0)

Comment: But if I kill my application the position will be save ? I would prefer that just in my application run .... Otherwise I'm going use a static class to save my attributes as derived Application

Answer (score 0):

Simply in your manifest file add following line to activity in which you want to retain position upon screen rotation.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```

Comment: This will work like a charm. Please dont forget to mark this post as answer if it works for you.Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes to your code. Basically you save the items when the activity is no longer active then restore them at the moment when you are creating your adapter not at the onRestoreInstanceState event.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<Trace> _traceDataset;
    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    TraceAdapter mAdapter ;
    String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trace_list);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvTrace);
        initList();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            // get saved items
            _traceDataset   = (ArrayList<Trace>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("items");

        }else{

            //create new list
            _traceDataset = new ArrayList<Trace>();
            //add some items to your list for testing
            initList();
        }
        // Set CustomAdapter as the adapter for RecyclerView.
        mAdapter =TraceAdapter(_traceDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public void initList(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Obj obj = new Obj();
            obj.setName(" GPS " + i);
            obj.setIndex("Element #" + i);
            _traceDataset.add(trace);
        }
        Log.v(TAG, _traceDataset.size());
    }

   /* @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("items", _traceDataset);
    }*/


    private int someVarA;


       @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //outState.putInt("someVarA", someVarA);
        outState.putSerializable("items", items);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        //someVarA = savedInstanceState.getInt("someVarA");
        Log.v("onRestoreInstanceState","onRestoreInstanceState");


    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // Save ListView state @ onPause
        Log.d(TAG, "ON PAUSE");
        super.onPause();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a comment on @Dominika's answer but i don't have reputation) Instead of saving the position in SharedPreferences try to save position in Singleton object. This way the position will be saved while the app is running, and when you kill the app, the position will be lost.

Comment: yes I can for example by derivating application  (getApplication)... I'm going look and sharedpreferences thanks